# Dependency problems with installing ia32-libs on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dependencies

I need to install the `ia32-libs` package on my Ubuntu server (version 11.10). When I try to install it via apt-get it says I need this dependency:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs : Depends: lib32v4l-0 (>= 0.5.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try and install `lib32v4l-0` I get this dependency:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 lib32v4l-0 : Depends: libv4l-0 (= 0.8.0-1) but 0.8.5-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to successfully install `lib32v4l-0` and `ia32-libs`?

EDIT: paste from `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
chris@ks395362:~/cssserver$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  at console-setup lvm2 ntpdate plymouth
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Can you paste the output from `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Sure, I've edited it into the post :)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to run `sudo apt-get install -f` to repair any broken installs. If that doesn't help, I may have to leave you to wait for a real Ubuntu expert to show up (which I am not).